# Block a site in IE without admin rights

Tags: internet-explorer, admin, blacklist

our organization sadly doesn't trust users with admin rights.

So... I want to block a couple time-wasting websites on my computer myself. Again, without admin rights.

I got Chrome covered but I also have to use IE for certain applications (sigh) and for some reason, can't find a way to block a simple website (say cnn.com) from my browser.

I can install about 30-40% of software without admin rights, but nothing .exe. That rules out many major players.

Can't change the hosts file.

Blocked from manually entering sites in IE.

Tried hosting a .pac file and configuring that with IE ... for some reason doesn't work even though every troubleshooter says the file is accessible and valid.

Quite the annoyance. Anyone have any ideas on how I can actually block a website from Internet Explorer without admin rights?

Not super important, but it's almost a challenge to me at this point.

Comment: Can this be done in a router? Also, you seem to be saying that you need to do the block but without admin rights and the users do have admin rights. If you are doing this on behalf of your organization then you should be able to have admin rights.

Comment: I'm simply a company cog and NOT on the IT team. While I can reach out to them I'd prefer not to everytime I want to change a block setting. Needless to say I cannot access any router. We don't get admin rights because 'security' ... what a laugh. We might download 'freemoney.exe' and run it on the network I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else wondering about this ... the pac file actually works just fine, I just needed to restart my computer for it to fully take effect, which is quite strange. That's because the pac files seemed to work instantaneously in Chrome and Firefox. For Internet Explorer, the turd sandwich of web browsers, an addition restart + praying to the computer spirits was necessary for it to actually do the GD'mned thing it was supposed to do.